I can´t acceess the button on the website in Python
I am trying to write python script which clicks on the button 'Consultar' on this webpage https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/taxas-de-titulos-publicos.htm using selenium library. The button  appears in the html code when I open it in the browser; however, when I try to do it with python, it gives me another html code without this button (even using dynamic content). Can you help me, please? The website is open to anyone, so you can try it yourself.
Tried everything!! All libraries for working with HTML

post what you have tried! also the result is available at this url https://www.anbima.com.br/informacoes/merc-sec/resultados/msec_10jun2024_ltn.asp, with the date in the format DDmmmYYYY

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Here is the selenium-python code(with explanation) to click on Consultar button.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/taxas-de-titulos-publicos.htm")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Below line will click on 'Prosseguir' cookie button. Use this code only if you are getting the cookie pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "LGPD_ANBIMA_global_sites__text__btn"))).click()

# Below line of code will switch driver context into the IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='full']")))

# Below line will click on the targeted button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@name='Consultar']"))).click()

# Below line will come out of IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(10)


Glad it helped. What should I do when someone answers my question?
